# Changes in the sizes of qualifiers across different platforms/systems

Tags: c++, c

I've been programming for quite a while in C and C++ and back in the beginner days, I came to know about the variation in sizes of different fundamental data types across platforms and system architectures. Like in C++, the standard stated the size of an `int` to be a minimum of 2 bytes (or equal to or greater than a `short`... I don't exactly remember). I know that it will vary and can take greater sizes as we move forward.

One thing I couldn't observe was change in sizes of qualifiers like `short`, `long` (and maybe `long long`). They were the same in different compilers and operating systems even though the data types grew in size and sometimes were equal in size with their long versions.

Just out of curiosity, are there any examples in the present where these qualifiers have a greater capacity or are they just fixed in size?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. Do you mean, like `long` was once usually 32 bits, and is now often 64?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yep. I've seen sizes of `int` jump upto 32 bits while coming from the old Turbo C++ compiler to a new one. But I've never seen the size of `long` change. I use Windows and I've been using different compilers but never seen a long become 64 bits (which `long long` has).

Comment: `long` has 64 bits on 64-bit versions of Linux, among other platforms. Others (including Windows) left it at 32, the minimum required size.

Comment: @Mike Seymour In 2014, my Windows `long` (in visual Studio) is 32 bits.  My Windows `long` (gcc w/Eclipse) is 64 bits.  More of a complier issue than OS one.

Comment: @chux, indeed I should have said GNU/MSVC rather than Linux/Windows. Sorry for the lack of pedantry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not "qualifiers", really. They half-describe distinct types. `short int` is a different type from `int`. Same with `long int` vs `int`. It is easy to be misled by the fact that (for example) the *simple-type-specifier* "`long`" resolves to the type `long int` (C++11 Table 10) as a form of syntactic sugar. But the rules for sizes of types is applied to the resulting types after this resolution; it is never defined in terms of the keywords `short`/`long` themselves.

And, yes, the sizes of those types have been subject to change just like the more familiar types have been; for example, `long int` is 4 bytes in contemporary 64-bit Visual C++, but 8 bytes in contemporary 64-bit GCC.

Comment: But `long`, `short`, `unsigned` etc. are not data types. They can be strapped onto any other fundamental data type, right? Besides, is there a way to specifically allocate sizes for a fundamental data type? Suppose `int` is 6 bytes on a system. Is there anyway to create an `int` of a custom size between 2 and 6 bytes? Will that be an issue?

Comment: @SangeethSudheer: As keywords on their own, no, but when they are used as an entire _type-specifier_, they are "short for" the full type, e.g. `long int`, `short int`, `unsigned int` (Table 10) and those are certainly data types. You can consider `long` on its own to be syntactic sugar for `long int`. There's no "strapping", per se. As _keywords_, yes, they're "strapped on" as described in 7.1.6/2 to form the full types. This all means that it's the full types you want to talk about, not the keywords in isolation. The meaning of `short`/`long`/`unsigned` hasn't and will never change.

Comment: Okay. So, they are also types but just with the syntactic sugars which makes me think they are some kind of an attribute for the data type. Thanks, didn't knew that. P.S. Is that really you in the pic? :)

Comment: @SangeethSudheer: All things are possible.

Comment: @SangeethSudheer Suspect the pic for Lightness Races in Orbit is a form of syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 3):

There are certainly examples: I know of systems (not all modern)
where `int` is 16, 32, 36 and 48 bits; I think that there have
also been cases where it was 24 bits or 60 bits (but those would
be really old machines), and maybe some other values as well.
And I've actually worked on a machine where `int*` was 16 bits,
but `char*` 32 (but that was a fairly long time ago).

Of course, a lot of these machines you're not likely to see
today, unless you work on embedded systems or mainframes.  (I
think a lot of embedded processors still have 16 bit `int`.)  On
the other hand, even on everyday desktop machines or laptops,
`long` may be either 32 bits (Windows and 32 bit Mac and Linux))
or 64 bits (64 bit Mac or Linux).

Comment: So, you're saying just like `int` and other data types have greater sizes on some platforms, `long`, `short` and others also vary and it's valid which is what I want to know about. I know that the data type itself has different sizes on different architectures but I want to know whether these "qualifiers" also change.

Comment: @SangeethSudheer Greater or lesser.  The minimums guaranteed are 8 bits for `char`, 16 for `short` and `int`, 32 for `long` and 64 for `long long`.  And nothing more.  (There's also no guarantee that the system will use 2's complement, and there are still mainframes that don't.)

Comment: Agree, many embedded processors use 16-bit `int`.  (Even worked with a non-compliant C) with 8-bit `int` - oh joy!).  But I have never come across a compliant C with `short` other than 16-bits.  I have _heard_ of some processors with 32-bit `char`, `short` and `int`.

Comment: @chux Some Unisys mainframes have 36 bit `short` and `int` (and 9 bit `char`, and 1's complement).  In earlier days, this arrangement wasn't that rare (except for the 1's complement), but today, your chances of encountering it are pretty small.